# While publishing the application into the Websphere application server it has to load all tables from database using spring

Tags: java, spring, ejb, websphere

In our project there is requirement to load all tables from database While publishing the application into the Websphere application server.

I just defined the applicationContext in classpath..
while publishing it is showing applicationContext in console
i wrote bean to retrieve all tables.
but is it possible to load bean without calling .getBean method

We are using EJB3 project not Webproject so it doesn't have web.xml to call applicationContext.xml

thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear at all... how do you plan to call applicationContext.xml from web.xml? Please edit your question to make it possible to understand

Answer (score 0):

Here is usual way to get the bean reference. Do you have any problems with is?

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
SomeBean someBean = context.getBean(SomeBean.class);
```